# Unity - Make a Sync Method that waits for user input

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface, synchronization

I have basic knowledge of **C#** with **WinForms** and **WPF**. But I am new to **Unity**.
I want to make a series of Message Boxes those appear one after another(once user close current than next box will show). It is very easy to use `MessageBox.Show("Hello World");` in **WinForms**.

```
void myFun(){
    MessageBox.Show("Hello World1");//First Box
    //Some Code
    MessageBox.Show("Hello World2");//Another

    MessageBox.Show("Hello World3");//Finally Results
}
```

In **WinForms**(or **WPF**) Code after `MessageBox.Show();` will not Executed before we Give input to close.

I want to make same **MessageBox** in **unity** with **GameObject** where code will not execute before **GameObject** is SetActive(False); by user command(mouse Click on Background or Yes/No Buttons).

Thanks in Advance

*sorry for bad English*

Comment: Because the Unity “UI” thread is the context you’re running in, you don’t want to be blocking that. Instead, you’d use one or some of: coroutines, Tasks, callbacks, events or polling in Update.

Comment: @MilanEgonVotrubec it’s a common misconception that coroutines somehow don’t block the UI thread - **they do**.  _[Why coroutines are dangerous](https://mickyd.wordpress.com/2022/10/06/implementing-time-based-delays-in-unity-3d/)_

Comment: Unity isn’t WinForms/WPF so you want to forget what you have learnt.  Unity has at least 3 different input APIs, take your pick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the best approaches becoming popular in Unity the last years is an **Async approach**. So I highly recommend you to learn this to have even more powerful tool than Coroutines and to avoid [Callback Hell](http://callbackhell.com/) in case of `Action` usage.

Let's implement it this Async approach together.

Firstly, we need that MessageBox implementation. Let's say it has 2 buttons: Confirmation and Cancellation. Here's it:

```
public MessageBox : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Button _confirmationButton;
    [SerializeField]
    private Button _cancelButton;
    
    private TaskCompletionSource<bool> _tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

    public void OnConfirmationButtonClick()
    {
        // we're passing `true` if user clicks `Confirm`
        _tcs.SetResult(true);
    }
    
    public void OnCancellationButtonClick()
    {
        // we're passing `false` if user clicks `Cancel`
        _tcs.SetResult(false);
    }

    public async Task<bool> ShowAsync()
    {
        gameObject.SetActive(true);
        
        // recreate an instance to not use the `SetResult` value of previous showing
        _tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        
        // the execution stops here ASYNCHRONOUSLY, so the UI thread is not blocked.
        // It just awaits until we set any result to `_tcs`
        await _tcs.Task;

        gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

And now we can show a few message boxes and await for their input. Moreover, we may know what exactly button was clicked: Confirmation or Cancellation:

```
public async Task YourOwnMethodAsync()
{
    // Let's assume you've instantiated 3 message boxes already and have their references

    var resultOfFirstMessageBox = await _messageBox1.ShowAsync();
    Debug.Log($"Showing the first message box shown. Result: {resultOfFirstMessageBox}");
    
    var resultOfSecondMessageBox = await _messageBox2.ShowAsync();
    Debug.Log($"Showing the second message box shown. Result: {resultOfSecondMessageBox}");

    var resultOfThirdMessageBox = await _messageBox3.ShowAsync();
    Debug.Log($"Showing the third message box shown. Result: {resultOfThirdMessageBox}");
}
```

If you need even more detailed description, just let me know.

Comment: Where do you actually display the MessageBox and wait for the result?  All you have shown is an async skeleton.  As soon as you do your async code becomes synchronous.

Comment: Although I have to use in await and async each time with this method.But still It will do the trick. Thanks.

Comment: @Honey22Sharp, and this is totally fine to start utilizing Task to start building the your game on async approach, it gives you tons of opportunities. Make a screenshot and come back to this advice in 2 years 

Comment: @Deleted showing the MessageBox and awaiting for the result is in the second code block, please check

Comment: No it isn’t.  Please check.